# Why do null values get returned from the page_fan table?

Tags: facebook-fql

Using the Facebook FQL query, I'm getting Null values returned in the created_time column. Is there a particular reason as to why there is no created_time values for certain facebook ids?

Here's my query, insert your own access_token.

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+uid,page_id,created_time+from+page_fan+where+page_id+in+(8576093908)+and+uid+in+(114385755252085,130258467128954)&access_token=insert_access_token

Answer (score 0):

It seems Facebook sought it not necessary to provide the `created_time` for pages

130258467128954 is a page

114385755252085 I think is a page as well, from some Googling it seemed to be the old DailyMotion USA page

In both cases `created_time` will not be returned. The correct scenario will be to return the time for the session user.